# jQuery - Access serialized data elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am editing some jQuery that another person has written.

Inside the $(document).ready(function() they have a bit of code as follows:

```
$(document).on('submit', ".editForm", function(e) {
    $.post( $(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function() {
        successMsg("Sorted.")
    })      
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

What i need to do is be able to access that serialized data on another click event.

How would i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)** with the `$(".editForm")` selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('submit', ".editForm", function(e) {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function() {
      successMsg("Sorted.")
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("#click").on("click", function() {
    alert($(".editForm").serialize());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="editForm">
  <input name="fname" value="John" />
  <br/>
  <input name="lname" value="Doe" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  <input type="button" id="click" value="click" />
</form>
```

If you want to get it as an array then use **[`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('submit', ".editForm", function(e) {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function() {
      successMsg("Sorted.")
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("#click").on("click", function() {
    alert(JSON.stringify($(".editForm").serializeArray()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="editForm">
  <input name="fname" value="John" />
  <br/>
  <input name="lname" value="Doe" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  <input type="button" id="click" value="click" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do i replace the $(this).serialize with what you have written? ... But how would i then access the data from another function?

Comment: to get data in another function u can use the above

Comment: BigJobbies, this answer makes sense to me. Check out this JSFiddle I just threw together, which uses this same approach: http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/55px3on4/ - Is it not what you were looking for?

Comment: Hey, yes it does make sense now .. Thank you